# sometimes button is not released after pressing and same for hover also in qt

Tags: qt

This is the code

```cpp
bool EventHandler::handleMousePressEvent(QPointF pos, Qt::MouseButton mouseButton)
{
    std::shared_ptr<EventInfo> pEventInfo = nullptr;

    m_bMousePressed = true;
    m_bMouseMoveReleased = false;
    m_timerTap.start();
    // Used incase of mouseMove event, to trigger Up event when the mouse pressed is moved outside screen item boundary.
    m_mousePressedPos = pos;
    if (getEventInfo(EventInfo::RHEventId::Down, pos, pEventInfo, mouseButton))
    {

        TRACE_OUT_F(F::EVENT_HANDLER,
                    _MF("EventInfo is updated with point = %1 , point.y =%2, pEventInfo->m_nElementId = %3")
                        << pos.x() << pos.y() << pEventInfo->m_nElementId);
        m_pScreenObjectVisualProxy->onTriggerMouseEvent(pEventInfo);
        TRACE_OUT_F(F::EVENT_HANDLER, _M("Event Triggered: Down"));
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is just some random custom code. Not a reproducible example.

Comment: What is getEventInfo, etc?